# convert a specific index of a javascript multidimensional object to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, multidimensional-array, ztree

iam using zTree jquery plugin and this plugin needs specific array object structure like this :

```
    var zNodes =[
        {id:1, title:"No right-click menu 1", open:true, noR:true,
            children:[
                   {id:11, title:"Leaf Node 1-1", noR:true},
                   {id:12, title:"Leaf Node 1-2", noR:true}

            ]},
        {id:2, title:"Right-click 2", open:true,
            children:[
                   {id:21, title:"Leaf Node 2-1"},
                   {id:22, title:"Leaf Node 2-2"},
                   {id:23, title:"Leaf Node 2-3"},
                   {id:24, title:"Leaf Node 2-4"}
            ]},
        {id:3, title:"Right-click 3", open:true,
            children:[
                   {id:31, title:"Leaf Node 3-1"},
                   {id:32, title:"Leaf Node 3-2"},
                   {id:33, title:"Leaf Node 3-3"},
                   {id:34, title:"Leaf Node 3-4"}
            ]}
    ];
```

as you can see its a mix of array and objects and when i (json_encode) from php everything turns into objects and i need a recursive function to convert the "children" from object to array but not the other contents of children except the children of children and so on

EDIT :

more on the subject :
http://jsfiddle.net/0mf78w4r/1/

SOLVED:

http://jsfiddle.net/0mf78w4r/2/

Comment: is this what you want ? http://jsfiddle.net/k1qhc7tc/

Comment: doing something wrong in your php then, where's the code creating the json? Seems like that would be a smarter to place to fix the issue

Comment: json_encode converts a multidimensional array into json ... then jquery reads this json and makes it into objects within objects i want some of these to be arrays not objects like this example above ... this is the json coming from php :
http://jsfiddle.net/83m6sxfa/